# Php and Ajax email form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i am totally new to ajax and just started getting a hang of php. So i got a ajax and php email code online that seemed to work on the first try and next few days suddenly kept returning with the error message which is "something went wrong". Please i'd appreciate if i could be put through on the source of this and how i could fix it. Thanks much

JS

```js
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Did you fill in the form properly?");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});


function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var msg_subject = $("#msg_subject").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&msg_subject=" + msg_subject + "&message=" + message,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Message Submitted!")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm").removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada animated text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

HTML

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contactForm">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" name="name" data-error="Please input your full name" required>
             <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" name="name" data-error="Please input your email" required>
             <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
             <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Your Message" rows="8" data-error="Write your message" required></textarea>
             <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="submit-button text-center">
             <button class="btn btn-common" id="submit" type="submit">Send Message</button>
             <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </form>
```

PHP

```html
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

// MSG SUBJECT
if (empty($_POST["msg_subject"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Subject is required ";
} else {
    $msg_subject = $_POST["msg_subject"];
}


// MESSAGE
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
}


$EmailTo = "name@email.com";
$Subject = "New Message Received";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Subject: ";
$Body .= $msg_subject;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Something went wrong :(";   //-->this is the error i get
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your logic is backwards, in your code an empty `$errorMSG` is good.

```
 if($errorMSG != ""){ // if NOT empty
echo "Something went wrong: ".$errorMSG; 
}else{
//good
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed it. I looked at my code over and over for hours and never saw that. Thanks a lot